# Why does accuracy score drop within a single batch?

Tags: python, neural-network

On my neural network I’m passing a dataset of 10,000 rows in batches of 10 at a time, the average accuracy score of all the batches is 55-57%, however there is a pqttern within every single batch: the first element always has an accuracy of 70% and then the second element is always lower and lower, and finally the last element is always the lowest at 49-51%.

Can someone please explain why does this happen and suggest how to make the accuracy score even through out the whole patch?

Comment: Please post more details regarding your issue. Your sample codes etc,